# Does every automorphism of a field of fractions restrict to the original ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, automorphism-group

Let $R$ be an integral domain, and let $F$ be the field of fractions of $R$.  Then my question is, does every field automorphism of $F$ restrict to a ring automorphism of $R$?  By $R$ I mean the natural embedding of $R$ in $F$.

I’m pretty sure that it’s true, but I’m not sure how to prove it.

Comment: What about an example with $R=\Bbb Q[x]$?

Comment: The converse is interesting: any example of field $K$ with $Aut(K)$ non-trivial, $K\not\subset \overline{\Bbb{F}}_p$ whose every subring $R\subset K,K=Frac(R)$ is such that $Aut(K)=Aut(R)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*EDIT: Berci's comment beat me to it!*

No, this needn't be true in general. Consider an "ambiguous" $F$ - a field such that there are two different $R_0,R_1\subseteq F$ each of which has $F$ itself as its field of fractions. If $R_0$ and $R_1$ can be "swapped" by an automorphism of $F$, this gives a counterexample.

The simplest example I can think of is $\mathbb{R}[t]$ and $\mathbb{R}[t^{-1}]$ as subdomains of $\mathbb{R}(t)$: there is an automorphism of $\mathbb{R}(t)$ which swaps $t$ and $t^{-1}$, and this clearly doesn't restrict to an automorphism of $\mathbb{R}[t]$ (or $\mathbb{R}[t^{-1}]$).